# Reuse Variable across Wordpress Templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, variables

I query some information in my wordpress blog's header.
How can I reuse the variable say in the sidebar of the blog?

If I try something like this in the sidebar, the output stays blank:

```
<?php if(isset($my_header_variable)) echo $my_header_variable; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Just make the variable [`GLOBAL`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) and it will be available.**

1) In your header.php:

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['skt'] = 44;
?>
```

2) In your sidebar.php:

```
<?php
echo $GLOBALS['skt'];
?>
```

And the value 44 will be correctly displayed. *I use this way and it works fine for me.*

Answer (score 0):

If the value is not going to change you can use `define`

```
 define("MY_VAR", "something");
```

Then to access later on

```
 if(defined("MY_VAR"))
      echo MY_VAR; // Will echo 'something'
```

Comment: There is a typo in your `if` statement.